# Programmatically add many versions to a Liferay Web Content

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have a Web Content in Liferay 6.2 and I want to add many versions to it, for test purposes.

How to do that without clicking thousands of times?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the script console (in Server Administration), set it to "Groovy",  paste the script below, replace the `userId`, `groupId`, `articleId` values with the ones found using the Liferay web interface, replace the `numberOfVersions` value with any number you want, then execute:

```
import com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext
import com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil
import com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.DLFolderConstants

int numberOfVersions=1000
long companyId=20155
long groupId=21328
String articleId="21333"
long userId=20199
long folderId = DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID
String content='<?xml version="1.0"?><root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US"><static-content language-id="en_US"><![CDATA[Bonjour]]></static-content></root>'

ServiceContext serviceContext = new com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext()
serviceContext.setAddCommunityPermissions(true);
serviceContext.setAddGuestPermissions(true);
serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(groupId);
serviceContext.setCompanyId(companyId);
serviceContext.setUserId(userId);

for (int i=10; i<numberOfVersions; i++) {
  double version = i/10.0
  JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.updateArticle(userId, groupId, folderId, articleId, version, content, serviceContext)
}
```

Any improvement or other idea is welcome!